# how to validate null string in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am getting null value in array brackets from api response and i am unable to validate this value.

> [null]

. how can i validate this. following is my code which is not working.

```
if(data === null) { return true; }

 if(data === '') { return true; }
```

below is my console screen show which is showing how data is coming.

[image]

Comment: `[null] === null` is not supposed to be `true`

Comment: Also, what does an empty string have to do with your input?

Comment: try if (data && data.length && data[0] == null)

Comment: Seems it is not matching API response standards. I would suggest asking your API developer to either return a blank array or an array with proper values!

Comment: @NikhilParmar Agreed!  That is a proper solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have solved this issue by change this response to string and then validate this.

```
var data = [null];
data = JSON.stringify(data);
if(data != '[null]')
{
//some condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution in JS for string:

```
const validateString = str => return str && str;
```